# How to use a Google Cloud Function to add timestamp onCreate to Firestore in Native mode

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The project in question was created through the regular Google Console. Not the firebase one.

I have entered the code below into the Cloud Console and associated with the onCreate event of my firestore database. The event is triggered correctly when I insert a document at specified the path. However the function always fails with

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined at exports.helloFirestore`

The document is created, but there is no "createdAt" field.

What am I missing?

*function*

```
exports.helloFirestore = (snap, context) => {
return snap.ref.set(
  {
    createdAt: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  },
  { merge: true }
)
.catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
   return false;
});
```

}

*Here is what it looks like in the console.*
[image]

Comment: Could you share your entire Cloud function code (i.e. full index.js) because it is not crystal clear how "The event is triggered correctly when I insert a document at specified the path.". Which path? Normally you would do something like `exports.createUser = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {})` to watch the `users/{userId}` path.

Comment: That is the entire could function. I didn't deploy it using the CLI, I used the Cloud Function Console.  The console lets you assign the trigger, event to listen to and the function to call.  (See the image) . The comment  in the code was inserted by the console when I chose the trigger, event type, and runtime.  My assumption is that you don't need `functions.firestore.document...` .  Perhaps you can't use the cloud console to write back to the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Firebase CLI to deploy code that response to events coming from Firebase products.  Your node project will need to have the firebase-functions module installed, and you will need to use that to build the trigger as show throughout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).  It's possible that you might be able to modify the function in the console after it's deployed, but the Firebase CLI is the only supported way of writing functions for Firebase products.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But does it matter that the project wasn't created as a Firebase project.  I did everything through the Google Console.  I chose to use Firestore in Native Mode for the database, thats all. ( i have updated the title to make this more clear. )

Comment: You probably have to use the Firebase console to at least activate Firestore for your project.

Comment: Firestore is working fine, and I never touched the Firebase Console for this project.

Comment: That is certainly not the norm. Consider using the CLI like the documentation suggests.

Comment: OK I see, Google Cloud Functions are not the same as Cloud Functions for Firebase. 

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/functions-and-firebase.

I set up a regular Cloud Function and although it can be triggered by a change to a Firestore database it doesn't appear to receive the same payload that a Firebase Cloud function would.

I am going to try to create a Firebase Cloud Function, but since this project is not a Firebase Project I don't know if it will work.  I'll report back.

Comment: the answer is "no" you can't